# How can reload __getitem__ so that, when key doesn't exist, can create it

Tags: python, python-2.7, dictionary

Is it possible to create a key value that does not yet exist, reload the method __ getitem__?

I try:

```
class Dict_(dict):
  def __getitem__(self, key):
     if key in self:
         self[key] = {}
         return self[key]
     else:
         return self[key]
```

I understand why there is a stack overflow, 
but I do not understand why there is no overflow

```
class Dict_(dict):
     def __getitem__(self, key):
         if key not in self:
             self[key] = {}
             return self.get(key)
         else:
             return self.get(key)
```

See description and see that when using get also uses __ getitem__ - D[k]

```
 D.get(k[,d]) -> D[k] if k in D, else d.  d defaults to None.
```

Please tell me, how to do what I want through `__getitem__`?

Answer (score 5):

You need to call the *original* `__getitem__`; using `self[key]` calls the top-level `__getitem__` and creates an infinite recursion.

Do this:

```
class Dict_(dict):
  def __getitem__(self, key):
     if key not in self:
         self[key] = {}
     return super(Dict_, self).__getitem__(key)
```

Note that the built-in Python `dict` type already has support for your use-case; if you define a [`__missing__()` method](http://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#dict) it'll be called automatically:

```
class Dict_(dict):
  def __missing__(self, key):
     self[key] = {}
     return self[key]
```

This is what [`collections.defaultdict()`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.defaultdict) *does*, provide a `__missing__` method that calls a provided factory method:

```
somedict = collections.defaultdict(dict)
```

Answer (score 2):

Martijn's (of course) correct in the use of calling the base `dict`s method and that you should look at `defaultdict`. However, you could "cheat" and define your `__getitem__` as:

```
class Dict_(dict):
    def __getitem__(self, key):
        return self.setdefault(key, {})
```

Answer (score 0):

You can Use `defaultdict` from collection if default value remain the same for a whole program run.

```
from collections import defaultdict
data = defaultdict(list)
```

If this value should be calculated in runtime  You can override `__getitem__` method

```
class Dict_(dict):
    def __getitem__(self, key):
        evaluated_value = [key]
        return self.setdefault(key, evaluated_value)
```