# overriding __iter__ in an ordered default dictionary

Tags: python, dictionary, iterator, infinite-loop

I have a somewhat complex data structure: a default ordered dictionary of ordered dictionaries, following what's coded [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34295811/611873). The class works fine, as I'm able to create ordered dictionaries by default if a key is missing. I would like to further extend the capability of this class, and override the `__iter__` method so that I can iterate only over the ordered dictionary of certain key. That is, if I have

```
import sys
import numpy as np
from collections import OrderedDict


class OrderedDefaultdict(OrderedDict):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):

        self.d = None
        if not args:
            self.default_factory = None
        else:
            if not (args[0] is None or callable(args[0])):
                raise TypeError('first argument must be callable or None')
            self.default_factory = args[0]
            args = args[1:]
        super(OrderedDefaultdict, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)

    def __iter__(self):
        for k in self[self.d].values():
            yield k

    def __call__(self, key):
        self.d = key
        return self

    def __missing__ (self, key):

        self.d = max(self.d, key) if self.d else key
        if self.default_factory is None:
            raise KeyError(key)
        self[key] = default = self.default_factory()
        return default

    def __reduce__(self):  # optional, for pickle support
        args = (self.default_factory,) if self.default_factory else ()
        return self.__class__, args, None, None, self.iteritems()

Tree = lambda: OrderedDefaultdict(Tree)
```

You see that the code saves the maximum key in a variable `self.d`, and I would like to iterate over its corresponding dictionary by default.

```
def main(argv=()):

    tree = Tree()

    tree[0]['n1'] = np.array([[3]])
    tree[1]['l2'] = np.array([[ 0,  4],
                            [ 4,  5],
                            [40, 41],
                            [41, 42],
                            [57,  3],
                            [57,  3]])
    tree[2]['t3x'] = np.array([[188, 401, 400],
                           [188, 187, 401],
                           [187, 205, 401],
                           [324, 306, 417],
                           [306, 305, 417],
                           [305, 416, 417]])
    tree[2]['q3'] = np.array([[188, 401, 400, 0],
                           [188, 187, 401, 0],
                           [187, 205, 401, 0],
                           [323, 324, 417, 0],
                           [324, 306, 417, 0],
                           [306, 305, 417, 0],
                           [305, 416, 417, 0]])

    for el in tree:
        print(el)

    return 0

if __name__ == "__main__":
    sys.exit(main())
```

In the code above, I try to iterate over the dictionary of the highest dimension. But this code doesn't work because I get into an infinite recursion in the `__iter__` method and I can't understand why. I've been following advice on how to implement this function [here](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/114568/iterating-over-the-values-of-a-list-of-ordered-dictionaries).

Comment: In the end of the first code block: `Tree = lambda: OrderedDefaultdict(Tree)`

Comment: Do you mean `for k in OrderedDict.__iter__(self[self.d]):     yield self[self.d][k]`

Comment: Yes! that worked, but why?

Comment: Having serious touchpad issues here,  it is essentially the difference between overriding something like getitem  with  `super(OrderedDefaultdict, self).__getitem__(key)` vs  `return self[self.d]` http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19861024/how-can-reload-getitem-so-that-when-key-doesnt-exist-can-create-it

Comment: With `for k in self[self.d]` you are calling `self. __iter__` so you end up with an infinite recursion

Comment: I get it, so you're basically calling `__iter__` on the super class? I thought the syntax was different for this.

Comment: Yes, `dict.__iter__` would also work, you just cannot iterate over self or self.values etc.. as they all call __iter__ so you just keep looping infinitely. With  `OrderedDict.__iter__(self[self.d]):` you are calling `OrderedDict.__iter__` not self.__iter__, you cannot add .values as again you would be calling self.__iter__

Comment: If you prefer you can use `for k in super(OrderedDefaultdict, self[self.d]).__iter__():` will also work